# The second chart in an HTML file is compressed vertically - display issue

Tags: javascript, html

I created a line chart in my HTML file. The following codes are the codes in my HTML file that are related to the line chart:

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  #chartdiv {
       height: 500px;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="selectordiv"></div>
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
      <div class="card-header py-3">
       <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Rain Data</h6>
     </div>
     <div class="card-body">
     <div class="chart-line">
      <div id="chartdiv"></div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/rangeSelector.js"></script>
<script>
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.paddingRight = 20;

var data = [];
            var visits = 10;
            for (var i = 1; i < 50000; i++) {
                visits += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10);
                data.push({
                    date: new Date(2018, 0, i),
                    value: visits
                });
            }
     
chart.data = data;
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.minZoomCount = 5;
dateAxis.groupData = true;
dateAxis.groupCount = 500;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.tooltipText = "{valueY}";
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 0.5;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

var scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

 var selector = new am4plugins_rangeSelector.DateAxisRangeSelector();
selector.container = document.getElementById("selectordiv");
 selector.axis = dateAxis;                  
    </script>
 </body>
```

I want to make a copy of this chart and put the new chart right under the original chart. I copy the codes and paste them under the original codes, and I got this:
[image: rain data]

Instead of displaying right under the original chart, the new chart is overlapped with the original chart and it is not displayed in the card area. I tried to copy the data from different places, but none of them can display my new chart properly. Please advise what should I do.

I was advised by user18074821 and changed the chart ID. The new chart can be displayed right below the original one now! However, it looks compressed
[image: Pic2]

Comment: It looks that you are missing an initial< in the line div class="card-body">

Comment: Sorry it's a typo. I edited it just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy the code you need to change the id "chartdiv" so that both copies do not use the same id. Change it both in the HTML and in the JavaScript

Comment: Your advice worked out! The new chart is now right below the old one, but it still has a display issue.

Comment: Try adding body { display:grid; }  in the <style> section.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: I solved it by changing the height in the <style> section. Thank you

Comment: Great to hear. You are welcome.